# Solving Schrödinger equation for state vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

I read a paper stating the Hamiltonian:

$$H = g\sum_m \left (a_{m+1}^{\dagger}a_m e^{i(\Delta t+\phi)} + a_{m}^{\dagger}a_{m+1} e^{-i(\Delta t+\phi)}\right) \tag 1$$

and the state of light:

$$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_m C_m(t)a_m^{\dagger}|0\rangle \quad . \tag 2$$

Solving the Schrodinger equation:

$$i\frac{d|\Psi\rangle}{dt} = H|\Psi\rangle \quad , \tag 3$$

they got

$$i\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = g\left( C_{m-1}(t) e^{i(\Delta t+\phi)} +C_{m+1}(t)e^{-i(\Delta t+\phi)} \right) \quad . \tag 4$$

I understood how they got the left-handed value, but did not get the right-handed one.
Maybe I did not understand how Hamiltonian operator works.

Could anyone explain this?

Here is the paper: https://pubs.aip.org/aip/app/article/6/7/071102/892590/Synthetic-frequency-dimensions-in-dynamically

Best regards.

Comment: Hi. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for MathJax. Also, consider to edit the equations and use \langle and \rangle to produce $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively. Lastly, please provide the full reference.